# Frontmatter and Chapter headings

Tags: fancyhdr, front-matter, book-class

I'm trying to format my thesis and I got to a pre-textual element (acronyms list) that has two pages. The first page has the correct "plain" heading, but the second page doesn't, because it's following the "fancy" heading.

I couldn't figure out how to fix this without messing with the `\maintmatter` part, which by now is correct. The Chapter page has "plain" style and the second page has "fancy" style.

How can I guarantee all pages to plain style in frontmatter and keep the distinction between chapter page and text pages in mainmatter?

```
\documentclass[oneside, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%Heading definition----------------------------
%Frontmatter and chapter page?
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
}

%overall?
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase \leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{A two-page pre-textual chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]

\mainmatter

\chapter{A two-page textual Chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: replace \mainmatter with `\thispagestyle{plain}
\mainmatter
\thispagestyle{fancy}
`

Comment: Yep, that's it. Is this logical? I mean, that's how usually one deals with `\frontmatter` or this standard behaviour (e.g. line headers) is supposed to be everywhere and not just in the `\mainmatter` section? And idk, If you make this as an answer I'd vote too.

Comment: `plain` style is only for title page, if you need more page to style it as plain, you should specifically say by `\thispagestyle{plain}`. 

i think \thispagestyle{fancy} is not necessary, it will work even if it is not given.

Comment: @TVMBoy Chaper pages use pagestyle `plain` too. Your `\thispagestyle{plain}` before `\mainmatter` only affects the last page of frontmatter. If the chapter in front matter has three or more pages your suggestion will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[oneside, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%Heading definition----------------------------
%Frontmatter and chapter page?
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}%
}

%overall?
\fancypagestyle{myfancy}{%
\fancyhf{} %
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase \leftmark}%
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}%
}

\let\oldfrontmatter\frontmatter
\let\oldmainmatter\mainmatter
\gdef\frontmatter{\oldfrontmatter\pagestyle{plain}}
\gdef\mainmatter{\oldmainmatter\pagestyle{myfancy}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{A two-page pre-textual chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]

\mainmatter

\chapter{A two-page textual Chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's good, I just had to add `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%` in "myfancy" definitions to show the line headers, maybe the code before set everything to 0, but it solved my problem anyway

Comment: the `\headheight` that you set as 15pt there ... is not the line's (rule's) height but the header's height that I thought you would like to have like this for some reason. Try changing the `\headrulewidth` like: `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}` instead of setting the `\headheight` there

Comment: Ok... you found that before I answer  .. nice catch ... Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[oneside, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%Heading definition----------------------------
%Frontmatter and chapter page?
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
}

%overall?
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase \leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{A two-page pre-textual chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]

\thispagestyle{plain}
\mainmatter
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{A two-page textual Chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The \thispagestyle{plain} before \mainmatter only affects the last page of frontmatter. If the chapter in front matter has three or more pages your suggestion will fail. Replace `\lipsum[1-5]` by `\lipsum[1-10]`. Additionally the `\thispagestyle{fancy}` after the chapter command can be removed.